# Is there an elegant way to convert a panda series of datetime timedeltas into formatted strings?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

This is the solution I have come up with, but I know there must be a better way to accomplish this. I've had quite a bit of difficulty manipulating these timedeltas.

```
import pandas as pd

df["End of Presidency"] = pd.to_datetime(df["End of Presidency"])
df["Start of Presidency"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Start of Presidency"])

df["Length of Presidency"] = df["End of Presidency"] - df["Start of Presidency"]
years, days = divmod(df["Length of Presidency"].dt.days,365)

yd = pd.concat([years,days], axis=1)
lamb = lambda row: "{} years, {} days".format(row[0], row[1])
df["Length of Presidency"] = yd.apply(lamb, axis=1)
df
```

An example dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')

#,End of Presidency,Start of Presidency
1,1797-03-04,1789-04-30
2,1801-03-04,1797-03-04
3,1809-03-04,1801-03-04
4,1817-03-04,1809-03-04
5,1825-03-04,1817-03-04
```

If you have any suggestions, I would greatly appreciate your help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create a `yd` dataframe, just `apply` on `Length of Presidency` column is enough.

```py
def get_year_and_month(value):
    year, day = divmod(value.days, 365)
    return "{} years, {} days".format(year, day)

df["Length of Presidency"] = df['Length of Presidency'].apply(get_year_and_month)
```

Or use lambda in one line

```py
df["Length of Presidency"] = df['Length of Presidency'].apply(lambda value: "{} years, {} days".format(*divmod(value.days, 365)))
```

The above needs you subtract `End of Presidency` and `Start of Presidency` previously. You can omit this with `apply` on dataframe by rows:

```py
df["Length of Presidency"] = df.apply(lambda row: "{} years, {} days".format(*divmod((row['End of Presidency'] - row['Start of Presidency']).days, 365)), axis=1)
```

If you don't want to show 0 in years and days, you can extend `get_year_and_month` function like:

```py
def get_year_and_month(value):
    year, day = divmod(value.days, 365)
    year = f'{year} years' if year else ''
    day = f'{day} days' if day else ''
    return ', '.join(filter(len, [year, day]))
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you very much for the in-depth answer. If possible, might you have an idea on how to go one step further and add in boolean logic here? For example, if days or years = 0, the string would only format as "n Years" or "n Days". Or might this be better to do after the fact with another function?

Comment: You're a legend mate. Thank you greatly!